# Why do I get an error when I leave out "from tkinter import *"?

Tags: python, tkinter, nameerror

In the following code I get an error when leaving out "from tkinter import *. I am confused as to the reason as I `import tkinter as tk`.
I tried modifying the function `set_text` without success.
The error is on
`self.e.delete(0,END)`
NameError: name 'END' is not defined`

Code:

```py
from tkinter import *

import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import ttk


class HelperFun():

    def set_text(self,parent,text):

            self.e.delete(0,END)

            self.e.insert(0,text)

            return    

    def __init__(self,parent):

        self.parent=parent

        self.e = tk.Entry(self.parent,width=10)

        self.e.pack()

        self.b1 = tk.Button(self.parent,text="animal",

                command=lambda:self.set_text(self.parent,"animal"))

        ...

root=tk.Tk()

HelperFun(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you.

Comment: whilst wildcard imports are allowed, for clarity it is best to avoid then:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0)

Answer (score 3):

When you use, from Tkinter import *, it imports all of the constants from that package, like END.
To get away without using this, you'd need to use the dot operator, like tk.END, otherwise it won't be defined.

Answer (score 3):

If you `import tkinter as tk` then you need to refer to `END` as `tk.END`.

Importing `from tkinter import *` imports everything in `tkinter`, making it so you don't have to use the `tk` qualifying prefix.

Comment: an easier thing tho would be to simply use the string `'end'`

Comment: @Bill the Lizard  Matiiss Thank you for the follow up. Your solutions solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

replace the line

`self.e.delete(0,END)`

with

`self.e.delete(0,"end")`

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't doing anything. And it is not showing `Button`

You cannot use `self.e` simultaneously in the `set text()` function.

The `Button` command isn't right.

I modified the code to make it more readability:

```
import tkinter as tk



class HelperFun():
    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.parent=parent
        self.e = tk.Entry(self.parent,width=10)
        self.e.pack()

        self.b1 = tk.Button(self.parent,text="animal",
                            command=lambda:self.set_text(self.e.get()))
        self.b1.pack()

        self.lb = tk.Label(self.parent, width=10)
        self.lb.pack()
    
    def set_text(self, _text):
        print(_text)
        self.lb.configure(text=_text)

        return    

root=tk.Tk()
app = HelperFun(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot before  and after clicking button:

[image]   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think in "(0,END)" you need to use 1.0 instead of 0.
Try "(1.0,END)"

Comment: This is certainly a best practice, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Why would you use `1.0` instead of `0` as a `tkinter` `Entry` index? It shouldn't be a float.

Answer (score 0):

END is like Button and Label ...
u have to write tk.END if u (import tkinter as tk)